# Find a positive decreasing twice differentiable convex function $f$ such that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx=\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Reopening this question:

[Does there exist a positive, decreasing, twice differentiable convex function such that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx=\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579990/does-there-exist-a-positive-decreasing-twice-differentiable-convex-function-su?noredirect=1#comment9646428_4579990)

**My trial:**

I tried some simple $f(x)$ like monomials or exponentials, that did not work (of course I may have overlooked smth). So I thought of being more systematic and try to define:

$$g(x)=\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}$$

where $g(x)>0$ from the hypothesis. I tried than to express $f$ as a function of $g$ like this:

$$f'^2=fg$$
$$f'=-\sqrt{f}\sqrt{g} \ (\text{take negative square root})$$
$$f'/\sqrt{f}=-\sqrt{g} \ (\text{divide by non-zero function})$$

and integrating from $1$ to $x$:

$$\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{f(1)}-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{x}\sqrt{g(x)}dx$$

so now we should find a positive $g(x)$s.t.:

$$\int_1^{+\infty}\sqrt{g(x)}dx <\infty,\int_1^{+\infty}g(x)dx =\infty $$

, or prove that such a $g$ does not exist but since it is very easy to make errors with such manipulations (taking square roots, divisions by $f$) I stopped here... moreover, maybe I am overcomplicating things...

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: it is not decreasing

Comment: What domain do you require $f$ to be defined on? If you accept $f:(1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ then 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\log(x)}$$
Then $x\mapsto \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}$ is (I think!) not integrable on its domain, because of the behavior near $1$.

Comment: @K.defaoite The question is about the integrability near $\infty$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The asker did not specify.

Comment: @K.defaoite You are right, but the context is quite clear here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction below is divided into two steps. In the first step, we construct a piecewise-linear positive decreasing convex function $f$, which is *not* differentiable only at integer points, such that the integral diverges; in the second step, we modify the function $f$ near the integer points to get a twice differentiable function $\tilde f$ satisfying all required peoperties.

***Step 1.*** In this step we construct a piecewise-linear positive decreasing convex function $f$ such that $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx=\infty.$$

Consider a sequence $\{a_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ with $a_1=1$ and $a_{k+1}=a_ke^{a_k}$ for $k\geq 1$, then $a_k$ is increasing to $+\infty$. We define a function $f:[1,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ such that $f(k)=\frac1{a_k}$ and $f$ is linear in each $[k,k+1]$:
$$f(x)=(f(k)-f(k+1))(k-x)+f(k)=\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)(k-x)+\frac1{a_k},\qquad x\in[k,k+1], \forall k\geq1.$$

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+1))^2\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{(f(k)-f(k+1))(k-x)+f(k)}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+1))\ln\frac{f(k)}{f(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)a_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{a_k}}\right).
\end{align*}
Since $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k=+\infty$, we have $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{a_k}}\right)=1\neq 0$, thus $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx=\infty$.

To show that $f$ is convex, it suffices to show that $\{f(k)-f(k+1)\}$ is decreasing in $k$. Let $\phi(x)=\frac1x-\frac1{xe^x}$ for $x\geq 1$, then $f(k)-f(k+1)=\phi(a_k)$. Since $a_k$ is increasing, it suffices to show that $\phi$ is decreasing in $x$. Indeed, we have
$$\phi'(x)=\frac{x+1-e^x}{x^2e^x}< 0,\qquad x>1.$$

***Step 2.*** In this step we modify the function $f$ constructed in Step 1 to get a twice differentiable  positive decreasing convex function $\tilde f$ such that
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(\tilde f'(x))^2}{\tilde f(x)}dx=\infty.\tag{1}$$

Recall that in step 1, the function $f$ we constructed is not differentiable only at $\mathbb N_{>1}$, hence we modify $f$ near each integers. To make things simplier, we look at a toy model first.

*Lemma.* Let $g(x)=|x|, x\in\mathbb R$. For any $\delta>0$, we can find a twice differentiable convex function $\tilde g:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ such that $\tilde g(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R\setminus[-\delta, \delta]$ and $|\tilde g'(x)|<1$ for all $x\in(-\delta, \delta)$.
*Proof of Lemma.* The function
$$\tilde g(x)=\begin{cases} |x|, & |x|\geq\delta,\\ -\frac1{8\delta^3}x^4+\frac3{4\delta}x^2+\frac38\delta, & |x|<\delta\end{cases}$$
will perfectly do the job. $\Box$[image: A picture for \delta=1]

Similar modification can be used for the function $k|x|$, where $k>0$; and then be used to general piecewise linear functions, as the following picture illustrates:
[image: Modifications]

We use this modification for the piecewise-linear positive decreasing convex function $f$ in $(k-\delta_k, k+\delta_k)$ for each $k\geq 2$, where $\delta_k=e^{-a_k}$. We denote the function after modification by $\tilde f$, then $\tilde f$ is a twice differentiable  positive decreasing convex function, and $$\tilde f(x)=f(x),\qquad \forall \ x\in\bigcup_{k=2}[k+\delta_k, k+1-\delta_{k+1}].$$

Finally, we check $(1)$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(\tilde f'(x))^2}{\tilde f(x)}dx&>\sum_{k=2}^\infty\int_{k+\delta_k}^{k+1-\delta_{k+1}}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+1))^2\int_{k+\delta_k}^{k+1-\delta_{k+1}}\frac{1}{(f(k)-f(k+1))(k-x)+f(k)}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+1))\ln\left(\frac{(1-\delta_k)f(k)+\delta_kf(k+1)}{\delta_{k+1}f(k)+(1-\delta_{k+1})f(k+1)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)\ln\left(\frac{(1-\delta_k)a_{k+1}+\delta_ka_k}{\delta_{k+1}a_{k+1}+(1-\delta_{k+1})a_k}\right)\\
& =\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)\ln\left(\frac{(1-e^{-a_k})e^{a_k}+e^{-a_k}}{e^{-a_{k+1}\ \ +a_k}+1-e^{-a_{k+1}}}\right).
\end{align*}
Since $$(1-e^{-a_k})e^{a_k}+e^{-a_k}>(1-e^{-a_k})e^{a_k}>\frac12 e^{a_k}$$
and
$$e^{-a_{k+1}\ \ +a_k}+1-e^{-a_{k+1}}<e^{-a_{k+1}\ \ +a_k}+1<2,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)\ln\left(\frac{(1-e^{-a_k})e^{a_k}+e^{-a_k}}{e^{-a_{k+1}\ \ +a_k}+1-e^{-a_{k+1}}}\right)&> \left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)\ln \frac{e^{a_k}}4\\
&=1-\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}-2\left(\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}}\right)\ln2\\
&=1-e^{-a_k}-2\frac1{a_k}\left(1-e^{-a_k}\right)\ln2\\
&\to 1,\qquad \text{as }k\to\infty.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(\tilde f'(x))^2}{\tilde f(x)}dx=\infty.$$
This completes the proof. $\Box$

***Remark.*** Using a smooth modification in the Lemma will give a smooth $\tilde f$ satisfying all desired properties here.

Comment: Just an observation: $f(k)$ satisfies the recurrence relation $f(k+1)-f(k) = f(k)\cdot(e^{-1/f(k)}-1)$. Sometimes the solutions of recurrence relations can be approximated by solutions of the corresponding differential equation, here: $f'(x) = f(x) (e^{-1/f(x)}-1)$. The advantage is that these solutions are smooth. Unfortunately, it does not work in this case. It can be shown that the solution of this differential equation exists for $x \ge 0$, but $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}dx$ is finite.

Comment: Hi @Feng thanks for your contribution. Very well written. For point 1 maybe I would have waited to define a_k after the computation of the integral in terms of the f_k. At the end it is the solution of the integral that motivates the definition if I understand correctly the idea.

Comment: Anyway compliments for getting up to the end (+1). I did not check everything you did but it sounds everything ok. I have to find the time to read the other answers and decide which one to accept. Yours has the qualities of being very clearly written and in some sense a "natural" approach.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your compliments and accepting. Your understanding is correct. $a_k$ was to be determined in my first computation. While writing this answer, I slightly changed the order and defined $a_k$ at the beginning, to make the answer a little bit shorter. Anyway, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the following construction is to find functions $h$ such that the solution of the initial value problem
$$
 f'(x) = -h(f(x)) \, , \, f(0) = 1
$$
is defined for all $x \ge 0$ and has the desired properties.

---

Let $h:(0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ be a function with the following properties:

1. $h$ is differentiable, positive, increasing, with $\lim_{x \to 0+} h(u) = 0$.
2. $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{h(u)} \,du= \infty$.
3. $\int_0^1 \frac{h(u)}{u} \,du = \infty$.

Then $H:(0, 1] \to \Bbb R$, $H(y) = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{h(u)} \, du$ is strictly decreasing with $H(1) = 0$ and $\lim_{y \to 0+} H(y) = \infty$, and we can define
$$
 f: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R, f(x) = H^{-1}(x) \, .
$$
$f$ is positive, strictly decreasing, with $f(0) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

$f$ is differentiable with
$$
 f'(x) = \frac{1}{H'(f(x))} = - h(f(x)) \,.
$$
This implies that $f'$ is differentiable and increasing (since $f$ is decreasing and $h$ is increasing), so that $f$ is twice differentiable and convex.

Finally,
$$
 \int_0^\infty \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)} \, dx = - \int_0^\infty \frac{h(f(x)) f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{h(u)}{u} \, du = \infty 
$$
where we have substituted  $u=f(x)$ in the last step.

---

It remains to show that such a function $h$ exists. With the substitution $h(u) = 1/g(1/u))$ this is equivalent to finding a function $g: [1, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ with the following properties:

1. $g$ is differentiable, positive, increasing, with $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$.
2. $\int_1^\infty \frac{g(x)}{x^2} \, dx = \infty$.
3. $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x g(x)} \, dx = \infty$.

We construct $g$ by defining sequences
$$
 1 = x_1 < y_1 < \ldots < x_n < y_n < x_{n+1} < \ldots
$$
converging to infinity, and define $g$ such that
$$
 \int_{x_n}^{y_n} \frac{1}{xg(x)} \,dx \ge 1
$$
and
$$
 \int_{y_n}^{x_{n+1}} \frac{g(x)}{x^2} \,dx \ge 1 \, .
$$
for each $n$. This guarantees that the conditions 2 and 3 are satisfied. The construction will also show that condition 1 is satisfied.

We start by setting $x_1 = 1$ and $g(1) = 1$. Now assume that everything is defined up to $x_n$. We set $y_n = x_n e^{g(x_n)}$ and $g(x) = g(x_n)$ for $x_n \le x \le y_n$. Then
$$
\int_{x_n}^{y_n} \frac{1}{xg(x)} \,dx = \frac{1}{g(x_n)} \log\frac {y_n}{x_n} = 1 \, .
$$
Finally, set $x_{n+1} = y_n + 1$ and for $y_n \le x \le x_{n+1}$
$$
 g(x) = g(y_n) + C_n \phi(x-y_n)
$$
where $\phi(x) = x^2 (3-2x)$ and $C_n > 1$ is chosen so large that $\int_{y_n}^{x_{n+1}} \frac{g(x)}{x^2} \,dx \ge 1$.

Note that $\phi$ is strictly increasing on $[0, 1]$ with $\phi'(0) = \phi'(1) = 0$, so that the piecewise defined function $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Nice and instructive. I guess the main reason for  forcing that functional form is the change of variables that one can perform in the integral right?

Comment: There are a lot of nice ideas I think and congrats for getting to the end. I will just accept @Feng answer because to me it sounds to require less ideas on top of each other. Even if your approach may be more elegant. Unluckily I cannot accept more than one answer :D i can just do +1...

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I started by substituting $u=f(x)$ in $\int_0^\infty \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}$, and with the observation that $f'$ can be expressed as a function of $f$ (if $f$ is strictly monotonic). – I tried for some time to find an “explicit” or “simple” function $h$ with the desired properties, but did not find one so far. That's why the function is defined  piecewise and recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistakes in your reasoning. There is such $g$, but given required properties I doubt there is any nice expression of it from elementary functions.

Given that we want integral of $\sqrt{g(x)}$ to converge and integral of $g(x)$ to diverge, we need $g(x)$ to take large values (otherwise we would just have $\sqrt{g(x)} > c\cdot g(x)$ near infinity). But for integral of $\sqrt{g(x)}$ to converge, we need $g(x)$ to take large values not very often.

So, the idea is as follow: if $g(x)$ is $2^n$ on interval with length $2^{-n}$, then this interval contributes $1$ to integral of $g(x)$, but only $2^{-n/2}$ to integral of $\sqrt{g(x)}$. If there is such interval for every $n$, then integral of $g(x)$ diverges, while integral of $\sqrt{g(x)}$ can still converge.

Let $w(x)$ be bump function: smooth, $w(x) = 0$ if $x \notin [0, 3]$, $w(x) = 1$ if $x \in [1, 2]$ and $0 \leq w(x) \leq 1$ if $x \in [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$.

Now, $h_n(x) = 2^n \cdot w(2^n \cdot (x - 10n))$ satisfies properties we required: integral of $h_n(x)$ is at least $1$, while integral of $\sqrt{h_n(x)}$ is at most $3 \cdot 2^{-n/2}$. Note that $h_n$ have disjoint supports for different $n$, so $\sum_n \sqrt{h_n(x)}\,dx = \sqrt{\sum_n h_n(x)}$.

Now, let add $\exp(-x)$ for positivity, it doesn't affect convergence, and say $g(x) = \exp(-x) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty h_n(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). Give me some time to review it and see if I understand everything (at least the weekend, a bit overwhelmed with things to do...). The answer is valuable from my point of view independently of this, but maybe you can already comment whether with your approach you are able to keep under control also the convexity property.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't followed the details but a positive function $g(x)$ with the desired property is
$$
g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{x-1}
$$

Then

$$
\int_1^\infty dx \sqrt{g(x)} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}} <\infty
$$

and
$$
\int_1^\infty dx g(x) = \infty
$$